# Is a function in Hilbert space Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, fourier-transform, lipschitz-functions

If $u\in H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, does $u$ satisfy Lipschitz continuity
$$\lvert u(x)-u(y)\rvert \leq C\lvert x-y\rvert\,$$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^2,$
for some constant $C$?

I believe this statement is correct, since $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has a Banach algebra property, and thus, $u(x)$ is bounded and continuous. However I am not sure how to show Lipschitz continuity directly, from properties of $H^2$ space, where
$$H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)=\bigl \langle u(x):\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\lvert u,\nabla u, \Delta u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)\bigr \rangle,$$
and the $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ norm defined from the Fourier Transform,
$$\lvert| u\rvert|=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(1+|\xi|^2)^2|\hat{u}|^2d\xi<\infty.$$

Comment: Because $\Delta u$ exists, $\nabla u$ must be continuous. Because $\Delta u$ is $L^2$, $\nabla u$ must be bounded.

Comment: How does it not? It is one of the most basic properties of Lipschitz continuity.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, very true, I think I overlooked it since I was trying to show it using Fourier Transform!

Comment: Is is not false that $\Delta u$ bounded implies $\nabla u$ bounded in dimension $2$ as it is the critical exponent for Sobolev embedding?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Note that $H^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is not embedded into $C^1(\mathbb{R}^2),$ but only $C^0(\mathbb{R}^2)$. And we only have the derivatives in the weak sense, so I am not sure that $f$ is Lipschitz after all.